# Synchronisation between System.Threading timer tick and background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I need to develop following scenario. I have System.Threating.Timer. On each timer tick, some values are retrieved from hardware device, this way:

```
lock (_synch)
{
  //Read some values
}
```

Also I have many methods invoked in background thread, they also wants to read/write on COM to talk with device, for example:

```
bool WriteSometghing ()
{
  lock(_synch)
   {
     //Write to device
   }
}
```

It works fine. All of this is synchronised as should, there are no simultaneous access to device from threads. However, I need to my WriteSomething method to be called asynchronously to prevent blocking other operations in my background thread. So WriteSomething should start third thread, do all needed operations and destroy third thread. Of course, still I need to be sure, that there are no simultaneous access to hardware. So it should be synchronised with method called on timer tick. Also I need to synchronise WriteSomething calls (every call is fired on UDP packet receive), so WriteSomething can be invoked simultaneously but all operations inside should be syncrhonised between WriteSomething calls.

Method WriteSomething has to be called from background thread and also third thread should be created from my background thread, in place of current WriteSomething call. Can I simply create third thread as I described, put WriteSomething there and leave my lock as is? Will it be synchronised as should between my 3 threads (first - timer tick, second - background thread, third - background thread for WriteSomething).

Can you give me some tips, how it should be done?

Comment: yes, `lock` will lock any and all other threads in your process, it doesn't matter if you started up a 3rd thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) to call `WriteSomething`.

```
var task = Task.Factory.CreateNew(WriteSomething);
```

That will spin up a new thread to execute the `WriteSomething` method. The `lock` inside the `WriteSomething` method will provide the necessary synchronization. If you want to harvest the return value, simply access `task.Result`.

Do note that accessing `task.Result` requires that the task complete. So if you write:

```
var task = Task.Factory.CreateNew(WriteSomething);
var rslt = task.Result;
```

The thread will block until the task is finished. Of course, you can do any arbitrary processing between when you start the task and when you harvest the result.

### Edit

If you can't use `Task`, there are other ways to do this. For example:

```
bool result;
Thread t = new Thread((s) => { result = WriteSomething(); });
// at some point you'll want to harvest the result:
t.Join();
// Now you can access result
```

Comment: No I can't because I'm forced to use .net 3.0 - unfortunately

Comment: @user1209216: See my update. Next time, please let us know about special conditions like a .NET 3.0 restriction.

Comment: Ok but join will block my thread and I want to avoid blocking. Also I don't need result to be retrieved this way, instead result will be sent via udp. I have udp server, it receives commands. I want to avoid blocking and process multiple commands simultaneously, with synchronisation. Result should be sent in response to received udp command.

Comment: @user1209216: If you don't need to join, then you can avoid using `Thread` and instead call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => WriteSomething);` However, the result will be sent via UDP as soon as it's available. Your receiver will have to be set up and waiting before you start the thread.

Comment: There are a few blocking methods, like WriteSomething. Some of them dont even have any result. Some others should send result as reply. Also there is method that only sends some cached value (retrieved previously on timer tick). Most important:when udp server receives command for that cached value, it should respond immediately. So blocking methods like WriteSomething should be moved to third thread, because they are triggered on the same listener inside my udp server. Can I use your solution with thread pool in this case?

Comment: @user1209216: Yes. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` spins up a thread. It just simplifies using threads, preventing you from having to create, start, and then join. It does all that stuff for you.

Comment: It looks really good, thanks for suggestion. I'm going to test it soon and then accept your answer

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is the best solution in my case, so I accepted your answer